# kqueue hangs with state 0x8 and size 4, using ZMQ

Tags: zeromq, kqueue

When I use ZMQ to receive messages over TCP on mac, I got the program using 100% of CPU after some hours. By using lsof, I found kqueue got into a wired state

```
myprogram 56486 user   13u  KQUEUE                                     count=4, state=0x8
```

and the grogram keeps waiting on something.

Can someone tell me what does state 8 mean in queue?

codes details:

language: Golang

package: github.com/pebbe/zmq4

```
    poller := zmq.NewPoller()
    // sub is the zmq socket over TCP that receives message
    poller.Add(sub, zmq.POLLIN)
    for {
        polled, _ := poller.Poll(zeroMQTimeout)
        if len(polled) >= 1 && polled[0].Events&zmq.POLLIN != 0 {
            msg, _ := sub.RecvMessageBytes(0)
            go handleMsg(msg[1])
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("something happened at %s\n", time.Now())
        }
    }
```

by loging, I see that the main goroutine hangs somewhere in the for loop, and it is likely to be at `sub.RecvMessageBytes`.

Using a blocking receive instead of a poller does not improve the situation.

Comment: And the code is?

Comment: @user3666197 more code details provided.  Pretty cool profile pic, BTW.

Comment: I'm tempted to add a "macos" tag, is that behaviour present on other systems, too? That said, general rules require you to extract and provide a [mcve] as part of your question. An external link to some larger project is not sufficient.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I agree with you. However, I haven't successfully reproduce the situation, which makes this an intermediate question on kqueue status.